# JHipster Monolithic with Nginx, What are JHipster Best practice for Monolithic Deployment?

Tags: jhipster

I have generated a monolithic application using Jhipstaer 6.5.1, I have generated prod war as par Jhipster doc mentioned
Now I want to deploy this application as a war in production, so I have some questions regarding it.

- Should I need to set war(tomcat) behind the Nginx server?
- As once Josh Long mentioned 'Make JAR, not WAR.', What are the best practices of Jhipster, should I go with war or fat jar (Jhipster Monolithic Case)?
- If the reverse proxy(Nginx) is required in case of war/fat-jar then should we need to configure SSL on both side, Nginx as well as tomcat level?

Comment: Avoid deploying into Tomcat or any app server, embrace the executable war/jar deployment model, it's what JHipster team promotes, if you deploy to an app server you'll have few issues to overcome and you win't find much help here as you will find out if you do a search on stackoverflow.

Comment: The reverse proxy is not required if you only want https, although it can provides you with other features like load balancing if you run multiple instances of your monolith.